# Making a home made projector bur lens an issur

Tags: optics

This got booted out if the lifehacker forum so I'll try here

I read a nice tutorial here which tells you how to make a homemade projector for two quid. Lovely thinks I so I trotted down to the local pound land, got me self some duct tape a shoebox and a couple of magnifying classes (exactly two pounds) and built it. So the result is not bad although not quite watchable (and you need to supermax the brightness on the iphone). The main problem I have however is that it remains slightly out if focus. I tried a 2x and a 3x lens and it was better with the three x but still not quite there. So my question is regarding how to choose a decent lens for this homemade projector. Does anyone have experience building it and choosing a decent lens. I want to make a cheap projector and I suppose this limits the lens options but I would happily spend a bit more than 2 pounds to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your problem is not that the image is entirely out of focus, but rather than you can only get one color to focus and the other colors get a bit blurry. There is also the possibility that you're getting the center to focus, but not the edges.

Alas, there is no good (2 pound) solution.

The first problem is called [Chromatic Abberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration) and there is no good solution. Either you get achromatic lens, composed of 2 or more different glasses cemented together, or you use an imaging mirror system, and neither is cheap.

The second is called [field curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petzval_field_curvature) and is well-known. Unfortunately, correcting the problem takes more optical elements and precision design, so it's not cheap either.

Comment: Do magnifying lenses without curvature exist?

Comment: Not 2-pound lenses.

Comment: What is the name of a non curved magnifying lens so I can look it up?

Comment: All lenses have _some_ field curvature. It's a matter of design effort and optical complexity and cost as to how close to perfectly flat the designer/maker wants to get. In your case, projection lenses are the obvious choice. They are designed to do exactly the job you want - flat source to flat screen, and minimum chromatic aberration.